# Getting size of UIView in init

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, uiview, ios10

I have made a custom subclass of UIView in my iOS application, and I am trying to get the computed sizes of the view in the view's init method, so I can use them when creating subviews to put inside the custom view.

The custom view is inside a stack view, which assigns my view 1/3 of the total (main view) height.

My init looks like this:

```
var mySubView: UIImageView

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    mySubView = UIImageView()
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    let viewWidth = Int(self.frame.size.width)
    let viewHeight = Int(self.frame.size.height)
    mySubView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: viewHeight)
    mySubView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

    self.addSubview(mySubView)
}
```

However, the heights and widths are not reported correctly. For instance, mySubView above only ends up filling about half of the total space of the custom view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think the view knows it's dimensions at this point during its lifecycle. Try getting the dimensions in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: You can't, not if it's the view controller's view. It's too early in the view controller's life cycle. You need to wait until (at the earliest) UIViewController.viewwilllayoutSubviews(). For that reason you probably should use auto layout constraints, many of which are already handled by a stack view. Create your custom view, add the subviews and constraints (in either IB or code) against the custom view, and it'll lay things out the way you need them.

Comment: @toddg is correct, the alternative to viewWillLayoutSubviews() (used by UIViewController) is viewWillAppear() (used by UIView). I tend to think in terms of the view controller for this. BEWARE: I believe both functions can be called more than once upon load, and also on things like orientation changes (and in iPad, multi-tasking).

Comment: Overriding layoutSubviews() in a UIView subclass is the earliest place in the view lifecycle where you can grab the view's frame (and use it to make decisions about how to layout subviews)

Comment: Perfect - moving the code into layoutSubviews() works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @rcca See my answer, yes you can do that, but you can also just use AutoLayout which is the same number of lines of code (4), but cleaner and type-safe. Also, I’ve shown a much easier way to “full size” a subview.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The initializer is called too early in the lifecycle of the view to accurately do layout unless you know the exact dimensions in advance. Even so, it is idiomatically the *wrong* place to do it.

Try using the `layoutSubviews` method as such:

```
class SubView: UIImageView {

    var mySubView: UIImageView

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        mySubView = UIImageView()
        mySubView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.addSubview(mySubView)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        mySubView.frame = self.bounds
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

Now the subview bounds will be set properly at the start of each layout pass. It’s a cheap operation.

Also, the `bounds` property of a `UIView` is the `frame` translated to the view’s internal coordinate space. This means that normally this is true: `bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)`. I suggest reading the documentation on view layout.

Alternatively, you can ditch manual layout entirely and use AutoLayout to do this for you.

```
class SubView: UIImageView {

    var mySubView: UIImageView

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        mySubView = UIImageView()
        mySubView.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.addSubview(mySubView)

        mySubView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        mySubView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        mySubView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor).isActive = true
        mySubView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I simplified the case a bit for my question here - in my application I don't want any of the subviews full-sized, but the issue is just that I need almost pixel-perfect fine control of their relative sizes. I tried using AutoLayout for a while, but I simply couldn't get it to lay things out the way I needed, so I figured a more manual approach might save me some time. :)